# Why is Kubernetes extension messing up my Helm charts?

Tags: visual-studio-code, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I noticed very recently that the Kubernetes VSCode extension from Microsoft is messing up my Helm charts. Here is an example.
Before:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "mybook.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "mybook.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
data:
  API_DEBUG: {{ .Values.mybook.api.debug | quote }}
  API_LOG_LEVEL: {{ .Values.mybook.api.logLevel }}
  DB_ENV: {{ .Values.mybook.dbEnv }}
  GUI_DIST: ./mybook/dist/mybook
  GUI_SOURCE: dist
  OPENID: {{ .Values.mybook.openID }}
```

After a save with the Kubernetes extension activated:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: { { include "mybook.fullname" . } }
  labels: { { - include "mybook.labels" . | nindent 4 } }
data:
  API_DEBUG: { { .Values.mybook.api.debug | quote } }
  API_LOG_LEVEL: { { .Values.mybook.api.logLevel } }
  DB_ENV: { { .Values.mybook.dbEnv } }
  GUI_DIST: ./mybook/dist/mybook
  GUI_SOURCE: dist
  OPENID: { { .Values.mybook.openID } }
```

Helm doesn't like the new format at all. The `helm template` command issues an error:

```
error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 4: did not find expected node content
```

I would be very interested to find any other solution than disabling the Kubernetes extension.

Thanks,
Timok